# the javascript window.print

Tags: javascript, html

In my HTML page I have:

```
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return image;
    }

    function printImg() {
        html2canvas($('#chart_div').get(0)).then( function (canvas) {
            var image = convertCanvasToImage(canvas);
            var htmlToPrint = image.outerHTML ;
            var newWin = window.open("");
            newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        });
    }
```

When I call the function printImg I get this error:

```
TypeError: newWin is null
```

What is missing?

Comment: Your browser is blocking the created window. You can only call `window.open()` _synchronously_ from a user event such as a `click` event listener.